# FormData() does not fetch empty select element with multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I am using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to fetch and submit form value using Ajax, It seem to do the job, however I noticed that when I define a multiple select element and when no value are selected for this field, it does not include with empty value, it simply ignores. But when I select any option then it works as expected.

What I want is, even if no options are selected, it must still include in data with an empty value. Is there a way I could achieve this?

Take for example input text or file, even if the value is empty, It does include it in the data with an empty value, why does it not do the same for multiple select element?

Comment: consider adding an default option in your list with value property set to empty & 'selected' property set

Comment: Thought about it, the problem is I am using bootstrap selectpicker, If I do that, placeholder is not displayed.

Comment: oh..well got your point..so then as of you are posting the data with ajax you can include the check to get value for control and if it return null or empty manually attach it to formdata object

Comment: Paste your code too, what you have tried so far.